# Using Excel Formula in VBA code with variable ranges

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently having a problem finding a way to vba an excel formula for all my columns in a worksheet. The number of rows in this worksheet is set to change from use to use hence it has to have a variable range.

The table currently looks like this:
[image]

I've got the value for noOfRowsOfData using:

```
Worksheets("Posttrans").Range("A1").Select
noOfRowsInPosttrans = Selection.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2
```

The formula I am trying to put at the bottom of the table is:

```
=IF(noOfRowsInPosttrans=COUNTIF(A3:A688,A2),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Where 688 is set to change to noOfRowsInPosttrans

This will keep it dynamic. I'm just wondering how I would go about inserting the formulas displayed.

Any help would be great!

Thanks,
PineappleBeans

Comment: It looks like you have a table so why aren't you using structured references?

Comment: Something like `Worksheets("Posttrans").ListObjects("Table3").ListColumns("//ck_Plan").DataBodyRange` will return the cells in the //ck_Plan column (excluding headers) - you'll probably need to change the name of the table.

Comment: Are you checking that all cells in column A from row 3 to the end are equal to A2?

Comment: @dcromley, yep that is the goal :) It's just a unique search

Comment: I don't think you need VBA for that.  There are any number of formula only options, I think.

Answer (score 0):

[image: example]
A6 = "=IF(COUNTIF(A$3:A5,A$2)=(CELL("row",A6)-3),TRUE,FALSE)"
Copy A6 to B6

EDIT: getting kind of crazy, but to show the formula:

```
Function function1(zcell As Range)
  function1 = zcell.Formula
End Function
```

Then A8 = "=function1(A6)" and B9 = "=function1(B6)" gives
[image]